# Get server side string value in client side using ajax call .net,C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I am creating one .net application. And i simply wants to get this "Hi" string in my ajax call. What i need to do? Now i am getting as undefined all the time. Nothing else.

My client side script looks like blow

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.cart').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            CallAddCart(id);
        });
    });
    function CallAddCart(ItemId) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SearchParts.aspx/AddShopCart",
            data: '{ItemId: "' + ItemId + '"}',
            contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                OnSuccess(data);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
   }

   function OnSuccess(response) {
       alert('On sucess' + response);
       alert(response);
   }         
</script>
```

And my server side looks like

```
    [WebMethod()]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string AddShopCart(string ItemId) 
    { 
       return "Hi";
    }
```

UPDATE:

The issue solved

That was one small mistake that caused these issues. The problem was with "contenttype" and "datatype". The both type's "t" which should be in capital letters. ie "contentType" and "dataType" :) now its able to get the Hi :)

Comment: Try to change this part: 
  public static string AddShopCart(string ItemId) 
    { 
     return string.Format("Hi")
    }

Comment: Ok i will check it

Comment: @RickBronger i changed it. But now its returning html content. do i need to alter something in my ajax On Success function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case sensitive which caused the issue. In below script i updated with the correct usage

Previuosly it was "contenttype" and "datatype". Now changed to contentType and dataType

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cart').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        CallAddCart(id);
    });
});
function CallAddCart(ItemId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SearchParts.aspx/AddShopCart",
        data: '{ItemId: "' + ItemId + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            OnSuccess(data);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
 }

 function OnSuccess(response) {
   alert('On sucess' + response);
   alert(response);
   }         
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll suggest to return value in JSON type

```
[WebMethod()]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string AddShopCart(string ItemId) 
{
   var result = new { d = "Hi" };
   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}
```

In Javascript

```
success: function (data) {
   OnSuccess(data.d);
}
```

Comment: What about return type of that function AddShopCart? Also JsonConvert not found error i am getting Do i need to use any namespaces for that?

Comment: So sorry about return value. It should be "return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result)" and return type is string. @NithinPaul

Comment: @NithinPaul Please see example in codeplex --> http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/752990/I-Want-to-return-JSON-webservice-using-Asp-net-csh

Comment: Now when i checked debugger i can see that Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'd' of undefined

Comment: The variable name 'data' is undefined ?

Comment: d is of data.d. and when i checked with plain data it is also showing undefined

Comment: @NithinPaul Please try the another solution as below.

Answer (score 2):

```
[WebMethod]
public static string AddShopCart(string ItemId)
{
    return "Hi";
}
```

Remove it. `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]`

In Javascript

```
success: function (data) {
   OnSuccess(data.d);
}
```

Credit: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Comment: The result is same :(

Comment: Oh man that was one small mistake that caused these issues. The problem was with "contenttype" and "datatype". The problem was with the type's "t" which should be in capital letters. :) now its able to get the Hi :)

Comment: Okay man that is a case study in sensitive of coding with Ajax :)